# Apply a function to named variables in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a data.frame `a`, and a vector of variables names `alist`:

```
a <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(20),x2=rnorm(20),x3=rnorm(20),x4=rnorm(20),x5=rnorm(20),x6=rnorm(20),x7=rnorm(20),x8=rnorm(20),x9=rnorm(20),x10=rnorm(20))
alist<-c("x3","x4","x7","x9")
```

How can I apply a function to `a` so that it affects only variables names in `alist` in a way that doesn't subset `a`? Meaning that the variables from `a` named in `alist` are replaced with the output of the function leaving rest of the variables unaltered.

I can always just run a function, for example `log(a[alist])` and just merge the output with `a`, but there must be a more direct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This generally works :

```
a[,alist] <- sapply(a[,alist], ...)
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. Similarly with `a[alist]<-log(a[alist])`.

Answer (score 0):

Following  works:

```
a[alist] = apply(a[alist], 2, log)
```

Above replaces values to log in only those columns of dataframe "a" that are specified in "alist".

Comment: True, it does, but if I were to run `apply(a[alist],2,log)` it would be the same as `log(a[alist])`. This output is a subset of `a` that does not contain the unaffected variables.